# How to append a string to next line in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a requirement described in the following.

This just a sample script:

```
$ cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash

perl -e '
open(IN,"addrss");
open(out,">>addrss");
@newval;

while (<IN>)
{
    @col_val=split(/:/);
    if ($.==1)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<=$#col_val;$i++)
        {
           print("Enter value for $col_val[$i] : ");
           chop($newval[$i]=<STDIN>);
        }
        $str=join(":");
        $_="$str"
        print OUT;
    }
    else
    {
        exit 0;
    }
}
close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

Running this scipt:

```
    $ ./test.sh
Enter value for NAME : abc
Enter value for ADDRESS : asff35
Enter value for STATE : XYZ
Enter value for CITY : EIDHFF
Enter value for CONTACT
 : 234656758
$ cat addrss
NAME:ADDRESS:STATE:CITY:CONTACT
abc:asff35:XYZ:EIDHFF:234656758
```

When I ran it the second time:

```
$ cat addrss
NAME:ADDRESS:STATE:CITY:CONTACT
abc:asff35:XYZ:EIDHFF:234656758ioret:56fgdh:ghdgh:afdfg:987643221  ## it is appended in the same line...
```

I want it to be added to the next line.

NOTE:
I want to do this by explitly using the filehandles in Perl and not with redirection operators in shell.

Comment: Why are you putting perl in a .sh file? seems a very roundabout way to do it, why not just use a .pl file?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add a newline to your string, before you print it out:

```
$_="$str\n";
```

Also, is there a reason why your script executes as bash, and you do a "perl -e" within the script?  Why not just make the script file execute as perl?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add a newline to the end of the string you print, this will work:

```
$_="$str\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print OUT $_ . "\n";
```

or

instead of print, use printf and add a line feed to the front or back.